# packet filter os x intermittently not blocking packets

Tags: macos, operating-system

Because parental controls on Mac OS is lacking functionality i wrote a script which changes the packet filter configuration based on time of the day. The script is executed based on a defined interval from a LaunchDaemon. When the pf.conf contents change the rules are re-loaded and the packet filter is enabled using -E which increments the reference count. (Yes, it does not release the previous token). It does the same when the packetfilter is disabled for one or another reason.

This works at first sight ok. Only after some time the packetfilter does allow outgoing requests to blocked domains. When it allows packets, `pfctl -s info` shows that the packetfilter is enabled and the pf.conf still does contain the configured rules.

```
sudo -s pfctl -s info
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
Status: Enabled for 0 days 10:21:37           Debug: Urgent

State Table                          Total             Rate
  current entries                        0               
  searches                        18191501          487.7/s
  inserts                                0            0.0/s
  removals                               0            0.0/s
Counters
  match                           17359675          465.4/s
  bad-offset                             0            0.0/s
  fragment                               0            0.0/s
  short                                  0            0.0/s
  normalize                              0            0.0/s
  memory                                 0            0.0/s
  bad-timestamp                          0            0.0/s
  congestion                             0            0.0/s
  ip-option                           2451            0.1/s
  proto-cksum                            0            0.0/s
  state-mismatch                         0            0.0/s
  state-insert                           0            0.0/s
  state-limit                            0            0.0/s
  src-limit                              0            0.0/s
  synproxy                               0            0.0/s
  dummynet                               0            0.0/s
```

The domain for which packetfilter seems to work the most bad is youtube.com. Other domains are also affected, but seems to occur less frequently. When making a http request to [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com), the response stalls for a couple of minutes and then returns the response.

```
% time curl https://www.youtube.com
<!doctype html><html  style="font-size:
...
/html>curl https://www.youtube.com  0.04s user 0.03s system 0% cpu 2:30.97 total
```

At the same time a http request to miniroyale2.io gives the expected timeout.

```
% time curl miniroyale2.io
curl: (7) Failed to connect to miniroyale2.io port 80: Operation timed out
curl miniroyale2.io  0.01s user 0.03s system 0% cpu 3:45.23 total
```

The script which periodically is executed by the launchDaemon is shown below.
Any suggestions how to reliably block outgoing traffic using packetfilter on mac os x or at least fix the packet filtering for youtube.com ?

```
#!/bin/zsh

pfctlfile="/etc/pf.conf"
changes=false

# packetfilter pf.conf lines should follow format
#
# BLOCK 08-23 RULEx
# block drop from any to {ip-addres}

##
## Keep pf.conf up to date
##

if [[ $(grep -c LOCKDOMAIN_3ea7 "$pfctlfile") < 1 ]] ;
then
cat << EOT >> $pfctlfile

## LOCKDOMAIN_3ea7

## youtube.com
#BLOCK 08-18 YT01
block drop from any to www.youtube.com
#BLOCK 08-18 YT02
block drop from any to youtube.com
#BLOCK 08-18 YT03
block drop from any to www.youtube-nocookie.com
#BLOCK 08-18 YT04
block drop from any to youtu.be
#BLOCK 08-18 YT05
block drop from any to www.googleapis.com
#BLOCK 08-18 YT06
block drop from any to www.googlevideo.com
#BLOCK 08-18 YT07
block drop from any to youtube-ui.l.google.com
#BLOCK 08-18 YT08
block drop from any to m.youtube.com
#BLOCK 08-18 YT10
block drop from any to ytimg.l.google.com
#BLOCK 08-18 YT11
block drop from any to googlesyndication.com

#games
#BLOCK 08-18 GAM1
#block drop from any to miniroyale2.io

EOT
fi

while read line ; do
     # extract start and stop time for
     IFS=" " read shour ehour <<< $(echo "$line" | sed -E 's/[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*BLOCK[[:space:]]+([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2}).*/\1 \2/')

     # get packetfilter definition
     packetfilter=$(sed -n "/$line/{n;p;}" $pfctlfile)

     # If current hour in timerange
     if [[ ( ($(date +%H) -ge ${shour}) && ( $(date +%H) -le ${ehour}) ) ]] ;
     then
       # if commented out (not active)
       if [[ ${packetfilter:0:1} == "#" ]] ;
       then
          # remove comment
          packetfilter=$(echo $packetfilter | sed -E "s/.{1}[[:space:]]*(.*)/\1/")
          # replace line
          sed -E -i "" "/^$line/ {n;s/.*/$packetfilter/;}" $pfctlfile
          changes=true
        fi
     else
        # if not commented out (active)
        if [[ ${packetfilter:0:1} != "#" ]] ;
        then
          # add comment
          packetfilter=$(echo $packetfilter | sed -E "s/[[:space:]]*(.*)/\1/")
          # replace line
          sed -E -i "" "/^$line/ {n;s/.*/#$packetfilter/;}" $pfctlfile
          changes=true
        fi
      fi

done < <(grep --line-regexp '.*#.*BLOCK\s\{1,\}\d\{1,2\}-\d\{1,2\}\s*.*' $pfctlfile)

## Reload config
if [ "$changes" = true ] ; then
  pfctl -Ef $pfctlfile
fi

## Re enable packetfilter if disabled
if [[ $(pfctl -s info 2>/dev/null | grep -c "Status: Enabled") < 1 ]] ;
then
  pfctl -Ef $pfctlfile
fi
```